# Render a new template with socketio.on() in Flask

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to do something along these lines:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/start')
def start():
    return render_template('start.html')

@app.route('/new_view')
def new_view():
    return render_template('new_view.html')

@socketio.on('change_view')
def change_view(message):
    return redirect(url_for('new_view'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

Basically I want it to redirect if it gets the 'change_view' message from the client. Right now it gets to the `change_view()` function after I click a button that triggers the `socket.emit('change_view', message)` call, so that part works. It just doesn't redirect or get into the `new_view()` function at all (i.e. if I put a print statement in `new_view()` it doesn't print). But it also doesn't give me any errors.  I am new to sockets so I'm guessing there's some fundamental misunderstanding going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, socket.io doesn't work like that. You can send a message telling the client to load a new page.

```
emit('redirect', {'url': url_for('new_view')})
```

Then in your client:

```
socket.on('redirect', function (data) {
    window.location = data.url;
});
```

But it's not clear why you need to hit the server at all for this particular example.

Comment: how to pass args to the `new_view` function?