# Flask socket.io redirect to template after socket.io event finishes

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I am receiving some socket.io event. After the event is handled I would like to redirect the user to some page. However, the redirection doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong. Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import base64
import os
import random, string

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    try:
        image_names = os.listdir('./images')
        print image_names
        return render_template("gallery.html", image_names=image_names)
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex

@socketio.on('takephoto')
def takePhoto(*args): 
    try:
        decoded = base64.b64decode(args[0])
        filename = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(6)) + '.jpg'
        with open("./images/" + filename, "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(args[0].decode('base64'))
    except Exception, ex:
        print ex

    redirect(url_for('index')) #This doesnt work
    #how can i go to index from this point?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
    app.debug = True
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5001), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I need this too!

Comment: After some searching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835432/render-a-new-template-with-socketio-on-in-flask). Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `return` statement.

```
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because return statement in socket.io context will return acknowledgement to the client, not the rendered page to the browser. I need something like artificial get request maybe? Or something like app.navigate_to(url)

Comment: Also I was thinking that switching context to app might help, but I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I just ran into this. Emitting a `'redirect'` event and sending `url_for('index')` all via sockets is your best bet.

Server side:

```py
emit('redirect', url_for('auth.login'), namespace=request.namespace, room=[request.sid])
```

Client side:

```py
socket.on('redirect', (dest) => {
   window.location.href = dest;
});
```