# Flask render template in socket.io callaback

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm using the Flask-socketio library for a python project and it seems it's not possible to use render_template in a socket.io callback. I could of course send the redirection url with emit and redirect my page in javascript like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835432/render-a-new-template-with-socketio-on-in-flask) but the problem is that I have to pass a variable in the render template. So I have a button on my index page that redirects to the process page and sends the process message with socket.io.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():  
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/process")
def format():
    return render_template('process.html')

@socketio.on('process')
def do_process():
    if process() == 0:
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
       return render_template('index.html', description=MSG_ERROR) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: Could you try something like this: `emit('my_event', {'url': url_for('format', description=MSG_ERROR)})`?

Comment: So it's the javacript that's going to render the error message?

Comment: Javascript will just redirect, rendering will happen in a template.

Comment: I have created a small app, with this type of workflow and it works. Let me know, if you need any help.

Comment: What is the benefit of using Socket.IO if you want it to behave just like a normal Flask route? A Socket.IO returns JSON data, not HTML. The use case is different than HTTP endpoints.

Comment: @Rig0L, any updates?

Comment: So I send the route with socket.io to the js client and I redirect from the js client. But this doesn't solve the problem of the message to display on my index.

Comment: How do you do the redirection in JS with this code : ```emit('my_event', {'url': url_for('format', description=MSG_ERROR)})```