# Flask redirect is not working - at least as I would

Tags: flask-socketio

This is a snippet of my code on the server side:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@socketio.on('message from user')
def receive_message_from_user(message):
    print ('USER MESSAGE {}'.format(message))
    emit ('from Flask', message.upper(), broadcast=True)
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

The client sends *message* from the *message from user* bucket. The server receives and prints it on the console, sends it back to all the connected clients (after having upperised it). **But it does not execute the redirect.** What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Possibly related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23835586/6168140

Comment: @big_bad_bison. Thank you. It works now. For completeness, I put the answer hereafter.